# "ionic serve" gives error "Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency"

Tags: ionic-framework

I have been trying to do

> ionic serve --address 127.0.0.1

all day with no luck due to the following error. Have been researching and investigating the issue for a long time now and hence this question here.

```
$ ionic serve
$ ng.cmd run app:serve --host=localhost --port=8100
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...
[INFO] Waiting for connectivity with ng...<br>
[INFO] Development server running!<br>
       Local: http://localhost:8100
       Use Ctrl+C to quit this process<br>
[INFO] Browser window opened to http://localhost:8100!<br>
[ng] i ｢wdm｣: wait until bundle finished: /
[ng] × ｢wdm｣: Error: No module factory available for dependency type: ContextElementDependency
[ng]     at addDependency (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:398:12)
[ng]     at iterationOfArrayCallback (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:80:3)
[ng]     at addDependenciesBlock (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:414:5)
[ng]     at iterationOfArrayCallback (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:80:3)
[ng]     at addDependenciesBlock (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:417:5)
[ng]     at Compilation.processModuleDependencies (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:425:4)
[ng]     at afterBuild (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:552:16)
[ng]     at _this.buildModule.err (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:598:11)
[ng]     at callback (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:349:35)
[ng]     at module.build.error (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:385:12)
[ng]     at resolveDependencies (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModule.js:219:4)
[ng]     at ContextModule.result.resolveDependencies (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\@ngtools\webpack\src\angular_compiler_plugin.js:517:25)
[ng]     at ContextModule.build (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModule.js:148:8)
[ng]     at Compilation.buildModule (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:353:10)
[ng]     at factory.create (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\Compilation.js:579:15)
[ng]     at hooks.afterResolve.callAsync (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\webpack\lib\ContextModuleFactory.js:150:16)
[ng] c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:16
[ng]     throw new Error('Callback was already called.');
[ng]     ^
[ng] Error: Callback was already called.
[ng]     at throwError (c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:16:11)
[ng]     at c:\Users\*******\Desktop\dev\app-name\node_modules\neo-async\async.js:2818:7
[ng]     at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:61:11)<br><br>
[ERROR] ng has unexpectedly closed (exit code 1).<br><br>
        The Ionic CLI will exit. Please check any output above for error details.
```

**Other details**

> 'ionic info' prints the following

```
Ionic:
   Ionic CLI            : 5.4.5 (C:\Users\******\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.11.4
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.12.4
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 7.3.9
   @angular/cli                  : 7.3.9
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.5.1
Cordova:
   Cordova CLI       : 9.0.0 (cordova-lib@9.0.1)
   Cordova Platforms : not available
   Cordova Plugins   : not available
Utility:
   cordova-res : not installed
   native-run  : not installed
System:
   NodeJS : v10.15.1 (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe)
   npm    : 6.13.0
   OS     : Windows 10
```

Hope I have shared sufficient information. Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to simulate following steps for the mentioned error.

1. Remove webpack from DevDependencies in **Package.json** file.
2. `rm -R node_modules` (To remove **node_modules** folder).
3. `npm i -g webpack`.
4. `npm i -g webpack-dev-server`.
5. remove **package-lock.json** file If it exists.
6. `npm i`(To install Node package again).
7. `npm start` (or `ionic serve`).

Comment: Welcome, Enjoy coding